# how to create JavaScript code for date object today + 11 days in JavaScript Shopify

Tags: javascript, shopify

I want to inject date into html in shopify description product

That it would say

We will ship the product from today + 11 days.....

And if it falls to saturday or sunday, it will be moved to monday cause we are closed on saturday or sunday

code is this for now, but dunno how to move it to first monday if necessary

```js
// get the destination within the DOM
var wrapper = document.getElementById('productEta'),

  // get today as a js Date object
  today = new Date(),

  // get the Unix of today (miliseconds) and add desired time (3 weeks)
  etaUnix = today.getTime() + (60 * 60 * 24 * 11 * 1000),

  // convert the new time to date object and then to a human readable string
  etaForHumans = new Date(etaUnix).toDateString();

// set the destination inner html to be what it already is
// plus a space and the human readable string.
wrapper.innerHTML += ' ' + etaForHumans;
```

```html
<div id="productEta">Product will arrive by: </div>
```

But something is wrong with the script also

Comment: try a search with "work or business days in Javascript", there are lot of questions that may give some clues.

Comment: Take more care in spelling *JavaScript*. http://javascriptisnotjava.com

Comment: I copied that code from shopify.....not my code...

Answer (score 0):

This actually ain't too hard.
The *Date* object provides a function **getDay()** which returns the day of the week.
It's an integer between 0 and 6.

You can do it like this:

```
var days = 4;
etaUnix = new Date(today.getTime() + (60 * 60 * 24 * days * 1000));
console.log(etaUnix.getDay())
switch (etaUnix.getDay()) {
  case 0:
    //sunday
    days++;
    break;
  case 6:
    //saturday
    days += 2;
    break;
}
etaUnix = new Date(today.getTime() + (60 * 60 * 24 * days * 1000));
// convert the new time to date object and then to a human readable string
etaForHumans = new Date(etaUnix).toDateString();
```

In the switch block where handling saturdays and sundays and simply adding one or two days to the date.

By the way - there are some typos in your code. There needs to be a **;** at the end of a statement not a **,**

Answer (score 0):

```js
// get the destination within the DOM
var wrapper = document.getElementById('productEta'),

  // get today as a js Date object
  today = new Date(),

  // get the Unix of today (miliseconds) and add desired time (3 weeks)
  etaUnix = today.getTime() + (60 * 60 * 24 * 11 * 1000),

  // convert the new time to date object and then to a human readable string
  etaForHumans = new Date(etaUnix);
  var day = etaForHumans.getDay()
  if(day==0)
      etaForHumans.setDate(etaForHumans.getDate() + 1);
  if(day==6)
      etaForHumans.setDate(etaForHumans.getDate() + 2);

// set the destination inner html to be what it already is
// plus a space and the human readable string.
wrapper.innerHTML += ' ' + etaForHumans+ ' ' + day;
```

```html
<div id="productEta">Product will arrive by: </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var wrapper = document.getElementById('productEta');
var today = new Date(Date.parse('2019-03-05'));
var etaDate = new Date(today.getTime() + (60 * 60 * 24 * 11 * 1000))
while(etaDate.getDay() == 0 || etaDate.getDay() == 6){
 //Add one day until it is not saturday or sunday
 etaDate.setTime(etaDate.getTime() + (60 * 60 * 24 * 1000));
}

var etaForHumans = etaDate.toDateString();
// set the destination inner html to be what it already is
// plus a space and the human readable string.
wrapper.innerHTML += ' ' + etaForHumans;
```

```html
<div id="productEta">Product will arrive by: </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

momentJS. Check it out. Allows you play with dates in a sane way. Has plugins for things like asking for the nextBusinessDay() and much more.

Don't fiddle with dates and vanilla Javascript unless you are an ace Javascript coder. It sucks and momentJS exists for good reason. Less suckage.